# macOS Sierra Terminal Vim Home/End keys

Tags: vim, macos-sierra

Since upgrading to macOS Sierra my home and end keys no longer work in vim.

They still work properly at the command prompt.

In terminal settings I have home set to send "\001" and end to send "\005".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've set my `Terminal` keys to \001 for ↖ and \005 for ↘. On my .vimrc:

```
map  <C-A> <Home>
imap <C-A> <Home>
vmap <C-A> <Home>
map  <C-E> <End>
imap <C-E> <End>
vmap <C-E> <End>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not a great option if you need to connect to a lot of remote servers and don't want to keep reconfiguring vim everywhere. I find that it is better to map the `Terminal` keys to `\033[1~` (Esc followed by `[1~`) and `\033[4~` (Esc followed by `\033[4~`).

There are still some servers that don't like using those codes on the command line -- SUSE Enterprise Linux maps these to `readline`'s `history-search-backward` and `set-mark` commands, so you might still have to modify `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` on those systems, but other Linux distributions don't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone end up with this problem using Mac with Ventra, in terminal setting, bind your Home to \033OH and your End key to \033OF.